# Is there any way to get dl, dt or dd tags by role in testing library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I would like to get `dd` tag by role using the testing library

```
<dl>
  <dt>ID</dt>
  <dd>123456</dd>
</dl>
```

I tried:

```
screen.getByRole('term', { name: 'ID' })
```

and

```
screen.getByRole('definition', { name: 'ID' })
```

But it didn't work

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "definition" and name "ID"

    Here are the accessible roles:

      term:

      Name "":
      <dt/>

      --------------------------------------------------
      definition:

      Name "":
      <dd/>

      --------------------------------------------------
```

The code below works just fine, but it finds the first element and there can be more than one

```
screen.getByRole('definition')
```

Comment: Yes there's a way to get them by role; that's what you're doing. But as the output tells you they don't have an [accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/) to be more specific. If you just want to select by the text content, you could e.g. `getAllByRole` then `.find` in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select an element `...ByRole("...", { name })` it needs to have an [accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/). The [W3 guidance](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/names-and-descriptions/) (for `dd`/`role="definition"` and `dt`/`role="term"`; `dl` has no implicit ARIA role) says:

| role | Necessity of Naming | Guidance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `definition` | Recommended | Reference the term being defined with `role="term"`, using `aria-labelledby`. |
| `term` | Do Not Name | Since a term is usually the name for the `role="definition"` element, it could be confusing if the term itself also has a name. |

Therefore you cannot select a *term* by name, but could select a *definition* by name if it was labelled by the appropriate term(s):

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

it("finds the definition by role", () => {
    render(
        <dl>
            <dt id="a">Denim (semigloss finish)</dt>
            <dd aria-labelledby="a">Ceiling</dd>

            <dt id="b">Denim (eggshell finish)</dt>
            <dt id="c">Evening Sky (eggshell finish)</dt>
            <dd aria-labelledby="b c">Layered on the walls</dd>
        </dl>
    );
    expect(
        screen.getByRole("definition", { name: "Denim (semigloss finish)" })
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Note that Testing Library uses [`aria-query`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aria-query) to make these selections.